# PHP / PDO / SQL Server. Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, php-7

I have a simple script which works in PHP 5.6 but does not work in PHP 7.0:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=10.6.2.105;Database=mydb", "myuname", "mypwd");
$sql = "SELECT TOP 3 txt FROM mytab";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row)
    print $row["txt"] . "\r\n";
```

When I run it in PHP 7.0, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver
```

According to http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php I don't need extension=php_pdo.dll in my php.ini file in versions above 5.3 for windows installs.

I do have the following though:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

Also, I can use sql server directly, just not with PDO.

What else do I need to get this working?  Where do I find the driver for this?

Details:

```
PHP 7.0.5
Windows 8.1
NTS x86
```

Comment: download the driver and add it to your ext folder and enable it on php.ini  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had already downloaded the driver and it didn't work.  Found a new site for the driver and this one works.

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

php.ini line added:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
```

Comment: would up vote this a hundred times. There are tons of threads asking this exact question, and this answer might be the only correct answer on the entire internet

Comment: @Matthew you are definitely right! I m trying all answers since morning including microsofts

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the documentation says that explicitly enabling the PDO extension is no longer required.

However, it seems like the MSSQL driver itself is not enabled in your php.ini file, as you are only listing MySQL, OCI and SQLite. So add this line to enable the extension:

```
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
```