# How can fix error PDOException: could not find driver?

Tags: php, sql-server-2012, sqlsrv

I have local site in `Wamp32`, `apache 2.4.23`, `php 7.0.10` and `mysql 5.7.14`

I wrote program to connect to `sql server 2014` in another server but when I run this program it has an error

> "could not find driver"

In `php.ini` I have:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll
```

My command for connect to sql server is:

```
 $connection = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=myserverIP;Database=mydatabase', 'username', 'password');
```

My server OS is `windows server 2012R2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP / PDO / SQL Server. Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792058/php-pdo-sql-server-uncaught-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: I update my php from 5.6.25 to 7.0.10 and now whe I type php in cmd it`s erroe is "the program can`t start because php5ts.dll is missingfrom your computer" I change the system path to php 7.0.10 and the another error is "unable to load dynamic library" for php_mysql and php_sqlsrv and php_pdo_sqlsrv